# UIWebView displays HTML too large

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to display a HTML into a UiWebView, but it shows the HTML too large, and it shows only partial content of the view. I have tried to change web view content mode, but it doesn't work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: I have tried it, it resizes a little bit but not at all, I'm trying to combine different parameters of the viewport to achieve it. Thanks!

Comment: yes, this meta tag along with webView.scalePagesToFit = YES; property.  Try removing the initial-scale option, and setting user-scalable=yes, as your web pages are not optimized for mobile devices.